# Windows batch file for loop

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to get a Windows batch file to run with a for loop.
The job should process multiple files but only gets as far as the 'steploop1' line below. The batch file is represented here:

```
cd %1
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo 'step1' >> C:\log.txt
for %%i in (%1%\*.*) do GOTO loop
echo done >> C:\log.txt
GOTO :end
:loop
    echo stepLoop1 >> C:\log.txt
    c:\cdpbuild.bat %%i %2 %3 
    echo stepLoop2 >> C:\log.txt
    echo submit file=C:\run.cdp 
    echo quit; | "C:\Program Files (x86)\..."
```

Could anyone tell me how I can get this to progress through the loop?

Regards

Comment: State `call C:\cdpbuild.bat %%i %2 %3` to return from the other batch file... and what's the last line of code for? to `echo` everything litterally? if so, escape the `|` like `^|`...

Comment: `goto` is just that. "Go to". There is no return, so no furher processing of your `for`. Use `call :loop` instead. Also `%1%` is wrong. It's `%1` only (typo?). Also for troubleshooting don't run your code with mouse-click. Open a `cmd` window and start it manually, so the window stays open to read any errormessages.